# Bind one-to-many models to datagrids WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have models structure like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        Authors = new List<Authors>();
    }
}

public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want somehow show the list of Books in 2 datagrids in WPF - One datagrid with books themself, when i select a row there - in second datagrids appears a list of Authors of the selected book.

How can I implement this? Probably I should use ObservableCollection, but how bind List to ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 3):

You should be having a ViewModel which has a collection of Books property and a SelectedBook property.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public Book SelectedBook { get; set; }
}
```

And the XAML goes like below,

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBook.Authors}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

in addition to the answer from XAML Lover. if you dont want the SelectedBook in your Viewmodel and just do it in your view you can use the following binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="books" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=books,Path=SelectedItem.Authors}"/>
```

Comment: It's so easy... I was running around observablecollections and got thouthands of errors. Thanks

Comment: This works well for read-only data, but when I want to edit records in the child table following exception shows up: `Additional information: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.`

Comment: so does authors not need to be an observable collection?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - from what I understand of your question - you have two grids side by side ( Say BooksGrid and AuthorsGrid)

Click on a row in the BookGrid should lead to the authors of that Book to show on the AuthorsGrid.

If you are using MVVM - @XAML Lover's reply should work. If not using MVVM - handle the DataGrid.Selected event in the code behind, from the selected row - get your book element and 
set the AuthorsGrid.ItemSource to the authors of the selected book.

Should be simple.